# cabal new-install hakyll is fails to build dependency

Tags: haskell, cabal, hakyll

After installing `ghcup`, I try to install `hakyll` with the command `cabal new-install hakyll`.
This leads to a build error in a dependency, the `text-conversions` library:

```
Failed to build text-conversions-0.3.0.
Build log (
/home/me/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.8.4/text-conversions-0.3.0-e3c3dbd414a885ff0e8ec81ad4c2c319c5dff5772ce6392ac561833941ecfd06.log
):
Configuring library for text-conversions-0.3.0..
Preprocessing library for text-conversions-0.3.0..
Building library for text-conversions-0.3.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.Text.Conversions ( src/Data/Text/Conversions.hs, dist/build/Data/Text/Conversions.o )

src/Data/Text/Conversions.hs:152:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String B.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘(B.ByteString, [Char])’
    • In the pattern: (bs, "")
      In a case alternative: (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
      In the expression:
        case Base16.decode (T.encodeUtf8 txt) of
          (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
          (_, _) -> Nothing
    |
152 |     (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
    |     ^^^^^^^^

src/Data/Text/Conversions.hs:153:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String B.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘(a1, b1)’
    • In the pattern: (_, _)
      In a case alternative: (_, _) -> Nothing
      In the expression:
        case Base16.decode (T.encodeUtf8 txt) of
          (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
          (_, _) -> Nothing
    |
153 |     (_,  _)  -> Nothing
    |     ^^^^^^^

src/Data/Text/Conversions.hs:164:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String BL.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘(BL.ByteString, [Char])’
    • In the pattern: (bs, "")
      In a case alternative: (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
      In the expression:
        case Base16L.decode (TL.encodeUtf8 $ TL.fromStrict txt) of
          (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
          (_, _) -> Nothing
    |
164 |     (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
    |     ^^^^^^^^

src/Data/Text/Conversions.hs:165:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String BL.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘(a0, b0)’
    • In the pattern: (_, _)
      In a case alternative: (_, _) -> Nothing
      In the expression:
        case Base16L.decode (TL.encodeUtf8 $ TL.fromStrict txt) of
          (bs, "") -> Just $ Base16 bs
          (_, _) -> Nothing
    |
165 |     (_,  _)  -> Nothing
    |     ^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build text-conversions-0.3.0 (which is required by
exe:hakyll-init from hakyll-4.13.4.0). See the build log above for details.
```

Any idea what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text-conversions` package is incompatible with the newest version of `base16-bytestring` that was released this week. So the build fails.

A short-term solution is to add a constraint, using the flag `--constraint="base16-bytestring < 1"` in the `cabal install` command, or adding the line `constraints: base16-bytestring < 1` to the file `~/.cabal/config`. ([Link to relevant section of the cabal documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-constraints))

On the long term, the `text-conversions` package must be fixed to add a version upper bound on a dependency `base16-bytestring < 1`. You can ask about the status of things in the following issues:

- https://github.com/cjdev/text-conversions/pull/10
- https://github.com/haskell/base16-bytestring/issues/14

Ideally (not necessarily), a new version of `text-conversions` compatible with `base16-bytestring-1.0.0.0` should be released, but it is still necessary to fix the bounds of existing versions to avoid ever picking up broken build plans.

Comment: Thanks so much Li-yao!  It builds now.